# how to move a block of lines to another position with sed?

Tags: linux, sed

how to move a block of lines to another position with sed ?

imagine a file like :

```
ligne
ligne
toto
tutu
titi
```

wanna get :

```
ligne
toto
tutu
titi
ligne
```

what is known pattern is "tutu" & the destination line number "2",
and origin lines number of the text bloc I want to move.

so I want it to be copied (with previous 1 line & 1 successive line) to specific position I already know (line n°2)

I tried :

```
sed '2,5{ H ;d ; } ;  2{ p ; x ; }' file
```

but the "paste" part doen't work so it displays only :

```
ligne
```

I do not really understand how to paste the buffer on a numeric value of a line; & that is what I want.

Comment: I'm afraid we've not enough details. How do we know "toto" should be moved when "tutu" is found? Where to stop moving (i.e. how many lines)? `Sed` can't do arithmetics, would e.g. `awk` be convenient?

Comment: just as written   I kown the pattern, "tutu" & want to move the whole patten (3 lines , 1 before 1 after)   to second line position to get result. I agree sed cannot do arithmetic but select line before & line after shoud be pattern-able ? no    (and yes if it is easier I can user either a vim script or a awk one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, just as written:

```
$ sed -n '1p; 2h; 3,/tutu/N; /tutu/ N; ${G; p;}' file
ligne
toto
tutu
titi
ligne
```

Comment: Thanks I've been able to adapt to my real context :) script

Comment: This only works with the OP sample (which is extremely "low quality" btw)... Try adding some more lines before `toto`...

Comment: @don_crissti: Yes it does. "Just as written" - they wanted 3 lines starting from line 2.

Comment: No, it does not. Your code will eat up any other lines that might be present before the pattern-1 line, as I said, try it yourself... He does not want 3 lines starting with line 2 he wants three lines (where the middle one matches a pattern) to be moved after the 1st.

Answer (score 1):

Not sed, but its ancestor [ed](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html):

- Match a range given by:

  - search for `tutu` then subtract one line
  - search for `tutu` then add one line
- `m`ove that block to line 2 (after line `1`)
- Save and quit (`w`, `q`)

Resulting in:

```
ed -s file <<< $'/tutu/-1,/tutu/+1m1\nw\nq'
```

Comment: There are at least a dozen duplicates which prove that `ed`/`ex` are the most suited tools for moving (multiple) lines (especially upwards...) yet people are masochistically trying to do it `sed`...